Dropzone in react not allowing for clickable uploads of needed file only dropping
I have a dropzone for file upload I cab drag and drop a file but cannot click and open file picker to upload it.
Here is my code:

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import './UploadButton.css';
import { ThreeDots } from 'react-loader-spinner';
const UploadButton = () => {
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [uploadStatus, setUploadStatus] = useState('idle'); // idle, uploading, success
const openModal = () => {
setIsModalOpen(true);
setUploadStatus('idle');
setIsLoading(false);
setSelectedFile(null);
};
const closeModal = () => {
setIsModalOpen(false);
setUploadStatus('idle');
setSelectedFile(null);
};
const onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
const file = acceptedFiles[0];
setSelectedFile(file);
setUploadStatus('idle');
};
const handleUpload = async () => {
if (selectedFile) {
setIsLoading(true);
setUploadStatus('uploading');
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', selectedFile);
try {
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/upload-csv/', {
method: 'POST',
body: formData,
headers: {
'Authorization': Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access_token")}
}
});
if (response.ok) {
setUploadStatus('success');
setTimeout(() => {
closeModal();
1000); // Close the modal 1 second after success
else {
alert('Failed to upload file');
setIsLoading(false);
setUploadStatus('idle');
}
catch (error) {
console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
alert('An error occurred while uploading the file');
setIsLoading(false);
setUploadStatus('idle');
}
else {
alert('Please select a file to upload');
}
};
const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({ onDrop });
return (


Upload CSV data from LinkedIn


Upload Connections.csv here
<div {...getRootProps()} className="dropzone">
<input {...getInputProps()} />
{uploadStatus === 'uploading' ? (



uploadStatus === 'success' ? (
<p style={{ color: 'green' }}>Upload successful!
) : (
<>
{selectedFile ? {selectedFile.name} : Select Files to Upload or Drag and Drop, Copy and Paste Files}
</>
)}



{isLoading ? 'Uploading...' : 'Submit'}


Cancel




);
};
export default UploadButton;

Css

.upload-button-container {
margin-top: 5px; /* Ensure there is space below the navbar /
text-align: right; / Align the button to the right */
}
.upload-button {
background-color: #1a1b3a;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 5px 10px;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.upload-button::after {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 2px;
background: #9b59b6;
transition: width 0.3s;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.upload-button:hover::after {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
transform: translateX(0);
}
.upload-button:hover {
background-color: #2a2b5a;
}
.loader-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 100%;
}
.modal {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
right: auto;
bottom: auto;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background: white;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
outline: none;
width: 400px;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.modal-overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.dropzone {
border: 2px dashed #ccc;
padding: 40px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-buttons {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.submit-button,
.cancel-button {
padding: 10px 20px;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.submit-button {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}
.cancel-button {
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
}

I was expecting the drag and drop as well as the file picker when I click to work
